# What does it mean in typescript: SomeInterface['someKey'][string]

Tags: typescript, interface, key

The data type which function will return **SomeInterface['someKey'][string]**, what does it mean? How the actual data instance look like? Is this an object? An array?

```
export const getSomething = (param: string): SomeInterface['someKey'][string] => { 
... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given a non-nullish type `T` and key-like type `K` which is a key of `T` (or a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of such key types), the type `T[K]` is an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) representing the type of value at that property key (or a union of those property value types).

Or, in other words, if `T` is the type of a value `t`, and `K` is the type of a value `K`, then `T[K]` is the type of `t[k]`.

For example:

```
let s = "hello"; // let s: string;
const l = "length"; // const l: "length"
const n = s[l]; // const n: number;
type N = string["length"]; // type N = number;
```

So `s` is of type `string`, and `l` is of type `"length"` (a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html)), and `s[l]` is of type `number`.  That means the type `string["length"]` is the same as `number`.

---

Back to your question: the type `SomeInterface['someKey'][string]` is therefore the type you'd get if you took a value of type `SomeInterface` (call it `si`), and index into it with a key of type `"someKey"` (so, `si.someKey`), and then index index into *that* with a key of type `string` (so, `si.someKey.xyz` assuming `xyz` is a key of `si.someKey`).  Something like this:

```
function foo(si: SomeInterface) {
  const sis = si.someKey; // SomeInterface['someKey']
  const k = Object.keys(sis)[0]; // string
  return sis[k]; // SomeInterface['someKey'][string];
}
```

Here, the function `foo()` will return a value of type `SomeInterface['someKey'][string]`.

---

Now, as for what type that actually *is*, that depends entirely on the definition of `SomeInterface`.  Apparently it has a key named `someKey`, and the property at that key has a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).

If, for example, it looks like this:

```
interface SomeInterface {
  someKey: {
    [k: string]: Date
  }
  someOtherKey: number;
}
```

then `SomeInterface["someKey"][string]` is `Date`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAzhC8ECIAWJjAPYINwQPS4lEigC5owAnASwDsBzLAKAGN0apJg5FR6wlseAq3acyCXnX4IWbDhBrcoAbWABdHPggj5NMjQCuAWwBGICkzABPAA4gIAOSWVadZRJB8BGoRGt3HbkNTcyZGADMDGmYwKjYIcPR0AAooKjIAZXQjEABJGjBzcIBDZhAASggAb0YIbTliKhh4NIA6KGyQAGkQK00CLJz8wooSsuUAcg6cnqsJtVr60QgAa24AeRMAKxAY1pXeqFSm8uUABh8tDmp6RYpwAwpFNJUVy4HO4aLSkEnp7t682U11cGkYAF9GIxaCMxvZBnkCt8ytVFv9ZmQanU6soVmQQfQ1GQACLFQqLSF1f7rfjmDEKYxmCwQqGMAAmu2AxXuS3kdHACP4rjIyRs3OKRnxLnolVgAD4IAivqMfn9OrMgQS6GCdJA2dx+WBBUhXMlkKgMAhyv1eXqSWSQKygA)